# GIt bash can't read my python file already tried the method under similar question

Tags: python, bash, git, command

The location of my python file is in My PC - `User -App data - Roaming -Microsoft-Windows-Start Menu-Python 3.8.` I tried the method by adding `"C:\Python38"` to Path under system variables. But when I type in `python --version`, it returns `bash: python no command found`; I also tried typing in the Path command recommended in the answer to the question "Git bash won't run my python files", still no. I use Windows system downloaded on Mac if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias in git bash

```
alias python='/c/Python3.8/...'
```

Then close and reopen the bash window and it should work.